# Javascript - Populate country code drop down onChange of country dropdown

Tags: html, select, country, dropdown

Is there any Javascript plugin to populate country codes on change of country dropdown?

Comment: Can you please show us your `html` code (at least). I'm guessing that you have 2 dropdowns. WHen the first changed you want to populate the other. Right? (`populate country codes on change of country` - country?

Comment: @Shyam I have updated my answer with a full code example for more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plug-ins, not that I know of... I know answers shouldn't only include external links, but I guess this might be exception, I will include a few links in case 1 breaks one day...
Since Country names and codes don't change too often nowadays might be safe with this text extract:

http://www.textfixer.com/resources/dropdowns/country-list-iso-codes.txt

then using [split(':')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function, easy populate text & value of select lists
options elements like this:

```
    function populateCountriesDropDown() {
        var file = "countries.txt";
        var selectList = document.getElementById('selectID');
        var rawlist;

        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
                if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                    rawlist = rawFile.responseText.split('\n');
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);

        for (var i = 0; i < rawlist.length; i++) {
            var country = rawlist[i].split(':');
            selectList.options[selectList.options.length] = new Option(country[1], country[0]);
        }
    }
```

OR other links with what you might be looking for:

http://www.freeformatter.com/iso-country-list-html-select.html

https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list